# Why evaluated list returns only number and error in other case?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure REPL:

```clj
('+ 1 2) ; 2
('+ 1 2 3) ; (err) clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (3) passed to: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Why it happens and how it works? I tried to inspect the code, but I can't figure out what is calling in function position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure symbols are functions too and are implemented like `get`.  So what you are calling here is `(get 1 '+ 2)`, which is OK (tries to look up `'+` in `1`, which can not work and therefor returns the fallback of `2`).  And the arity just does not work; only 1-2 arguments allowed.